# Why Netty Spring react class requires to be component AND define router with as bean

Tags: reactjs, spring, kotlin, netty, javabeans

I'm ramping up on Kotlin with Spring Netty and don't understand when specifying a router bean the class it pertains to ALSO has to have the `@Component` tag.

The example I'm reading states that when creating a router class I need to define it as -

```
@Component
class CustomerRouter {

@Bean
fun customerRoutes():RouterFunction<*> = {
.....
```

I was expecting that a class defined as @Component gets picked up by the class analyzer and have an instance of it created, therefore NOT requiring to specify the `@Bean` aspect as well.

But in this aspect, using React - if I remove `@Bean`, then it ceases to work.

Can someone explain the logic behind that? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The `@Component` is so that component-scanning can pickup the `CustomRouter` class and create a bean out of it. The `@Bean` is on the `customerRoutes` method, indicating that this method is a factory method for a `RouterFunction`. In the end you have 2 beans in your context, 1 for the `CustomRouter` (Which is probably better of as an `@Configuration`) and a `RouterFunction` one. Both are needed and hence yo need both annotations.

Comment: Yes, but why are both needed? That's what I don't get.

Comment: Because without `@Component` it will not be detected and thus the `@Bean` won't be parsed. Without the `@Bean` it is just a method of a class which won't produce a bean.